# Angular uibmodal loader

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, uib

could anyone guide me of how to add a loader to uibmodal to be shown until content gets loaded.

I do not need it to be only in one case I need it a default behavior.

Comment: What are your content? Are you filling your modal with an `$http` request's response?

Comment: yes using http request

Comment: So make your $http request, then use `$uibModal.open()` in `success` block and add a loading on your http requests.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9zK6S55GwH2Oi1Ja?preview) . Rather than `Loading` , you can put `<img>` which will show a spinner gif

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
    <div><div class="modal-header">
      <h1 class="modal-title"> Modal</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div ng-show="!($ctrl.data)">Loading</div>
         {{$ctrl.data}}
    </div>
</script>
```